# ASP.NET Core MVC SignInManager and ajax request problem

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-ajax

I have an ASP.NET Core identity SignInManager implementation. All works. I can login/logout/add/delete...All is fine, however now I have a need to submit an ajax request to the controller, but because controller is only available to Authorized users (I can not insecure the action so it has to be for authorized users), and I don't know how to change my ajax request so that it takes the correct headers so that my request is allowed by controller.

Can some kind soul help / guide please?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you need an '[AllowAnonymous]' attribute upon the relevant controller action(s) (?), to (in some cases / for some actions) permit anonymous/unauthenticated users.

Comment: I am afraid that is not an option, for form security, it has to be only authorized users..
Thanks anyways

Comment: In some cases it can be the need for setting 'withCredentials' to 'true'.

Comment: Any one please...?

Comment: DennisVM-D2i, it took me sometime before I determined that your response (withCredentials=true) was correct answer. Thanks
I set the xhrFields:{
withCredentials=true
}